# Trim white spaces of value in input

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, whitespace

Help needed for a newbie. I'm having a hard time deleting white spaces from input in the submit form. Here's the way I tried to do it:

```
var usernameInput = document.querySelector('.setup-user-name');
var newValue = usernameInput.value.trim();
usernameInput.value = newValue;
```

After that form should go through validation like that:

```
usernameInput.addEventListener('invalid', function () {
  if (usernameInput.validity.tooShort) {
    usernameInput.setCustomValidity('Имя должно состоять минимум из 2-х 
символов');
  } else if (usernameInput.validity.valueMissing) {
    usernameInput.setCustomValidity('Обязательное поле');
  } else {
    usernameInput.setCustomValidity('');
  }
});
```

Even though I use the `trim` method I'm still able to submit the form with spaces in the input.

Comment: because there is no validation about white spaces.

Comment: Furthermore `trim` removes white spaces only from the begin and the end. Is it that what you intend to do?

Comment: Yes, that's my intention @Quasimodo'sclone

Comment: It isn't clear if you want to *automatically sanitize* the input, or *signal errors when it's invalid*. Which do you want?

Comment: @GershomMaes I want to be able to see signal errors when it's invalid.

Comment: So why are you ever trimming the value, and doing `usernameInput.value = newValue`? That's *sanitization*, not *detecting invalid input*. Perhaps edit your question to show how this all fits together?

Answer (score 6):

You can prevent users from entering usernames containing leading or trailing spaces by using the html `pattern` attribute and using regex to define what an acceptable username looks like:

```html
<p>Try entering a value with leading and/or trailing spaces</p>
<p>If the form disappears that means the value was accepted</p>
<form enctype"...">
  <input class="setup-user-name" placeholder="username" pattern="^[^ ].+[^ ]$" />
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

You'll note the regex I used here is:

`^[^ ].+[^ ]$`

- The initial carat symbol (`^`) means "the beginning of the string".
- The sequence `[^ ]` means "any character but a space"
- The sequence `.+` means "anything at all; minimum 1 character"
- The sequence `[^ ]` again means "any character but a space"
- The final `$` symbol means "the end of the string"

This regex defines an "acceptable" value as one which doesn't have a space directly after the beginning of the string, or directly before the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript trim method only removes whitespace from both sides of a string.

```
var str = "  this is sample string  "
console.log(str.trim()) // "this is sample string"
```

if you want to remove  all white spaces you can use replace method

```
var str = "  this is sample string  "
console.log(str.replace(/\s/g, "")) // "thisissamplestring"
```

if  you are thinking of validation then you should use your own validation or use other libraries for validation, these methods only return new string of specified value and does not perform any validation

Comment: That's not what I need to do. I need to remove spaces from both sides.

Comment: I know but it isn't working for some reason. I'm still getting the value of my input with spaces. @SR Thapa

Comment: i think that you should check the values that is returned after applying trim method and before applying trim method. It may be your submitting input value that is not trimmed.

Comment: What's the value that you are trying? @MaksimSenko

Comment: @SASIKUMARS Trying what?